# RCurl::url.exists() : how to get non-error for redirects (in the 300 range of HTTP status codes)

Tags: r, redirect, curl, error-handling, rcurl

I have a bunch of URLs extracted by text-mining some PDF documents. Now I want to test the URLS for validity. Some urls have junk characters inside or appended, or the URLS are truncated. One approach is to filter them by calling each of them.

To do that, I use the  `url.exists()`  function from the RCurl package. The function makes HTTP HEAD requests to urls using curl and checks the status code.

From the documentation of `?url.exists`

```
 If ‘.header’ is ‘FALSE’, this returns ‘TRUE’ or ‘FALSE’ indicating
 whether the request was successful (had a status with a value in
 the 200 range).
```

How can I make it return TRUE for urls that issue a redirect? Redirect status codes are in the 300 range. They are not really errors.

Or is there a better way? grabbing the actual status codes and process them manually? Should I use a system command here?

Comment: Checking the return code certainly seems reasonable. If you don't like that approach you should probably define "better way".

Comment: You might want to look at `url_ok` and `url_success` in httr: since httr automatically follows redirects, these reflect the success of the final url.