# Increase maximum redirects allowed in RCurl

Tags: r, redirect, error-handling, rcurl

I am trying to write a script that takes a list of URLs and returns a vector specifying whether each website is up or not (TRUE or FALSE).

The problem is that the `url.exists()` function from the RCurl package returns an error (i.e. FALSE) for redirect status codes in the 300 range, which are not really errors (at least the sort I am concerned with). This problem was identified in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343560/rcurlurl-exists-how-to-get-non-error-for-redirects-in-the-300-range-of-ht).

To address this problem, I am using the `url_success` function from the httr package.

However, this produces another error when I run it on certain websites, for example:

`> url_success(site_list[621])`

`Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  :`

`Maximum (10) redirects followed`

Is there a way to change the maximum redirects allowed by RCurl?

Or is there an alternative way to approach my problem in general here?

Answer (score 0):

In **RCurl**, try something like:

```
url.exists(url, maxredirs=-1)
```

Comment: Hi there, I have tried this but it doesn't work. Is there a way to specify a timeout for `url.exists`? I can't seem to find anything about it.

Comment: @timothyjgraham Basically all RCurl options are direct translations of libcurl options. Look here and see if there's something that looks appropriate: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html

Comment: Thanks, I have looked at the libcurl options. However the timeout option seems to be ignored??? I am not sure if I'm getting the syntax wrong? `url.exists("www.badURLxyz101.com",.opts=list(timeout(5))`

Comment: @timothyjgraham You should specify parameters in the form `timeout=5`, though the default `0` seems to be zero (meaning it never times out), so your issue is probably not timeout-related. You're probably going to have to supply the actual URLs that you're getting errors for.

Comment: An example of the problematic URLs is http://architecture-wales.com/ . Thanks for all your help. It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @timothyjgraham That comes in as clearly not existing when I attempt it, so I'm confused about what you want the response to be.